# How to set special ringtone for all foreign numbers?

Tags: ringtone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Separate ringtone for calls from numbers not in the contact list?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/separate-ringtone-for-calls-from-numbers-not-in-the-contact-list)

How to make all numbers except of "+375..." play different ringtone (or set ringtone just for this pattern of numbers)?

Also I want to set other special ringtone for unknown (not in phonebook) numbers. I don't want to specify ringtone for every record in phonebook.

Comment: You might want to check [Separate ringtone for calls from numbers not in the contact list?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/separate-ringtone-for-calls-from-numbers-not-in-the-contact-list).