# How to decline all calls from numbers not in your Contacts in DND mode?

Tags: calls, do-not-disturb, oneplus6t

I am on holiday, and would like prevent all calls from numbers that are not in my Contacts such that the caller will not know that my phone is on. 
I do not want the callers of not-in-my-Contacts know that my phone is on. 
The caller at the moment can note that I am receiving the call.

I select *Do not Disturb* -mode, but still call is going on and the phone is receiving the call: I can disable visual notification as in Fig. 1, but the caller will know that my phone was on. 
I want that the phone is automatically declined.

DND mode:

- I select DND -mode from the top bar.
- Configuring the setting as in Fig. 1 such that no visual notification from call in DND -mode.

Figure 1. Restrict notifications: disable visual notification when the caller is calling.

[image]

I know the thread [Separate ringtone for calls from numbers not in the contact list?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/separate-ringtone-for-calls-from-numbers-not-in-the-contact-list) 
but there is no longer *Interruptions* in *Settings* so the [proposal](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/181796/9897) there cannot be applied.

The best answer would of course be with the native setting to do the thing, but 3rd party application proposal is also welcome.

I do not like the macro solution approach in the thread [Block all calls from area code unless in Contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172174/9897).

Phone is not rooted.

Known bug in OnePlus 6/T in the thread [Do Not Disturb mode not working](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/do-not-disturb-mode-not-working.931247/) (beeshyams).

OS: Android 10, update feb 1st
Phone: OnePlus 6T

Comment: @beeshyams not rooted.

Comment: Just to be sure, in DND mode did you choose the option of allowing calls from [contacts only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fMop.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block calls for everyone except for contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52833/block-calls-for-everyone-except-for-contacts)